# How do I copy this dynamic array into a spreadsheet and why don't boilerplate answers work for me?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, cell

I have written a VBA script to filter entries in an Excel table based on the contents of another one. I understand that although my table contains multiple fields (columns) they are contained within a 1D dynamic array.

I assigned a range in a workbook, and then resized this to reflect the size of the dynamic array. I then try to bulk assign the contents of the dynamic array to the range.

```
Sub generate_motor_list_from_QlikView_data()

 Dim tags As Variant
 Dim mtrs() As Variant
 Dim msng() As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim k As Integer
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim mtrtbl As Range

 ReDim Preserve mtrs(i)
 ReDim Preserve msng(j)

 tags = Worksheets("Backend").Range("Tags[Tag]")

 For Each Tag In tags
  Set rng = Worksheets("QlikView").Range("QlikView[Tag]").Find(What:=Tag, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
   If rng Is Nothing Then
       msng(j) = Tag
       j = j + 1
       ReDim Preserve msng(j)
       ' do something !
   Else
       Set mtrs(i) = Worksheets("QlikView").ListObjects("QlikView").ListRows(rng.Row - 1)
       i = i + 1
       ReDim Preserve mtrs(i)
   End If
 Next Tag

 Set mtrtbl = Worksheets("Backend").Range("F18")

 mtrtbl.Resize(UBound(mtrs, 1), 1) = mtrs

End Sub
```

The debugger brings up this message, on the line `mtrtbl.Resize(UBound(mtrs, 1), 1) = mtrs`

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Your `mtrs` is from `0` to `i`. If it contains at most one element, `UBound` is 0, and that is an invalid value for `Resize`. When you fix that, you will see that it outputs the same array value in all cells starting from F18, this is because a 1D array goes to the right on an Excel sheet, not down. To make it go down, [Transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) it.

Comment: @GSerg That appears to work but I've just discovered a new problem... Run-time error '-214767261 (80004003) Method 'Transpose' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed. From what I can gather the contents of each element in mtrs is too big to fit in a single cell. The table rows contain 18 fields

Comment: Transpose cannot handle text longer than 255 characters per cell, that is a well known Excel restriction (for many cases, not just Transpose). In that case, make `mtrs` a 2D array to begin with (`i` rows, 1 column).